# err_cleartext_not_permitted error while running Dapp on Android Metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps

I use Metamask browser on Android phone to connect to a Dapp.

But it gives `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`.

This Dapp is working well on browswer extension Metamask.

All connections in `web3.js` source is secured (HTTPS).

How can I fix the error?

Comment: Can you provide a small example to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should active ssl services in your web page hosts. thats it. i try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In laravel Project
I used this at the end of the web.php or api.php file and it worked perfectly:

URL::forceScheme('https');

In Another Technologies force Your users to go to https urls to solve this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).